# Pandas: How to handle columns with mixed types

Tags: python, pandas

I am reading a csv file with columns that contain mixed data types. I am not sure what to do.

First, this is the data that I am using: https://www.kaggle.com/epa/fuel-economy/data

Now I am reading that file in:

```
    data = pd.read_csv('data/database.csv', sep=',')
```

This the error message I am getting:

```
DtypeWarning: Columns (7,16,62,64,65,67,68,78) have mixed types. Specify dtype option on import or set low_memory=False.
  interactivity=interactivity, compiler=compiler, result=result)
```

Now I'm wondering what to do.
I could add `low_memory=False` or set the data type of these columns wihtin the `read_csv` method. My problem is that I am not sure what kind of type I should set it to, because that dataset is that huge and I can't figure out what data type would be the best for each column.

Could someone help me with my problem?

Comment: `I could add low_memory=False` that probably is the solution. Its hard to say what would be best datatype for each column. Pandas does that automatically.

Answer (score 0):

To get a printout of the type of data, I did the following:

create an iterable of the dataset

assign to variable the 1st chunksize

```
df_chunks = pd.read_csv('database.csv', sep=',', chunksize=5)
df1 = next(df_chunks)  # df1 is a dataframe of the first 5 rows
```

get the type of data for the first row:

```
for i, t in enumerate(df1.iloc[0]):
    print(type(t))
```

(as the printout is long, you can append to a list or create a dictionary with keys the column names and values the types for easier lookup)

or:

```
df1.info()
```

Hope this helps!